Azure Devops: Showing field finish date in work item detail view
sorry for the newbie questions. I´m new to Azure Devops and I´m trying to show the finish date in the work item detail view.
Any idea, if this is possible?
I tried to use configuration of processes to show field. Probably someone can recommend a good training for Azure Devops.

Hi @Matthias, have you tried the suggestion below? Did it work for you?

Hi @Matthias, what's the latest state of the issue? Have you been a member of the Project Collection Administrators group, or have the corresponding collection-level permissions Create process, Delete process , Edit process, or Delete a field from organization set to Allow?

You need to use inherited processes and add Finish Date field to the work item.
Go to Organization Settings -> Process -> ... (More actions) -> Create inherited process.

Select your target work item type -> New field -> Use an existing field -> Finish Date.

Go to Layout, you can add field Finish Date into an existing group or create a new one.

Then it looks like this:


Thank you, I will try it but noticed that I´m missing some permissions.

Hi @Matthias, to create an inherited process and manage it, you must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group, or have the corresponding collection-level permissions Create process, Delete process, Edit process, or Delete a field from organization set to Allow. For more information, see Set permissions and access for work tracking, Customize an inherited process.
